# Cropping an image

Tags: ios, uiimage

I use two different methods to crop the center square out of this image. One works, one doesn't. My question is why.

[image]

Here are the two results:
[image]

Clearly, the left is buggy and the right works.

The image you see on the left uses only `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect` to 
select the region of the image, where the rect is scaled by the ratio of the
original image dimensions to those of the view's dimensions. **Why doesn't this method work**?

The image you see on the right translates the image and then selects the region
of interest with the origin at 0,0 using `CGImageCreateWithImageInRect`

Here's the code that draws both images:

```
- (UIImage *)cropImage:(UIImage *)original inRect:(CGRect)rect {
    CGFloat heightScale = original.size.height / self.view.frame.size.height;
    CGFloat widthScale = original.size.width / self.view.frame.size.width;
    CGRect scaledRect = CGRectMake(rect.origin.x * widthScale, rect.origin.y * heightScale, rect.size.width * widthScale, rect.size.height * heightScale);

    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(original.size, YES, 1.0);
    [original drawAtPoint:CGPointMake(-scaledRect.origin.x, -scaledRect.origin.y)];
    UIImage *translatedImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

    CGRect finalRect = CGRectMake(0, 0, scaledRect.size.width, scaledRect.size.height);
    CGImageRef imageRefForRightImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([translatedImage CGImage], finalRect);
    CGImageRef imageRefForLeftImage = CGImageCreateWithImageInRect([original CGImage], scaledRect);

    UIImage *croppedRightImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRefForRightImage];
    UIImage *croppedLeftImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRefForLeftImage];

    CGImageRelease(imageRefForRightImage);
    CGImageRelease(imageRefForLeftImage);

    UIImageView *colorImageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.frame];
    colorImageView.backgroundColor = [UIColor purpleColor];
    [self.view addSubview:colorImageView];

    CGRect rectLeft = CGRectMake(0, 0, 160, 160);
    CGRect rectRight = CGRectMake(160, 0, 160, 160);

    UIImageView *croppedImageViewLeft = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rectLeft];
    UIImageView *croppedImageViewRight = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rectRight];

    croppedImageViewLeft.image = croppedLeftImage;
    croppedImageViewRight.image = croppedRightImage;

    croppedImageViewLeft.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
    croppedImageViewRight.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;

    [self.view addSubview:croppedImageViewLeft];
    [self.view addSubview:croppedImageViewRight];

    croppedImageViewRight.image = croppedRightImage;
    croppedImageViewLeft.image = croppedLeftImage;

    return croppedRightImage;
}
```

Comment: What is the value of `inRect:rect`?

Comment: Its simply the loss of translation data. Try changing the left to `UIImage *croppedLeftImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRefForLeftImage scale:original.scale rotation:original.rotation];`

Comment: @JackWu The result is the same. Still buggy.

Comment: @matt `scaledRect` is `origin=(x=329.0625, y=703.098572) size=(width=421.875, height=422.535217)`